# for/as a birthday present

Tags: vocabulary

> (1) I gave her a pouch **for** a birthday present.
>   (2) I gave her a pouch **as** a birthday present.

Can the two above all be used? If they do, Isn’t there nuance difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are acceptable.  I agree with Tetsujin that #2 sounds better, and ngram shows a considerable preference for "as".  `(for a birthday present),(as a birthday present)`

P.S. No nuanced difference in denotation, only in how it strikes the ear.

Comment: Here's the link to the Ngram:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+a+birthday+present%2C+as+a+birthday+present&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20birthday%20present%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20a%20birthday%20present%3B%2Cc0

Comment: How did you do that link, @tunny? When I tried to make such a link a week or two ago, I got an error message saying that links to ngram were not allowed--though I cannot remember if that was here or on ELU.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember., I think I went to https://books.google.com/ngrams and entered the two phrases. I then copied the URL (or whatever the term is for the thing at the top of the page) and pasted it in my comment.

Answer (score 5):

(2) is the form I'd use, of the two examples.

(1) bothers me but I couldn't quite say why.
I would recast it as "I gave her a pouch for her birthday"